# It was round the part of the day

Tags: phrase-meaning

[**Source**](http://efront.readingandwritingproject.com/public/resources/student_writing/ms_2013/ms/seventh/Narrative/Narrative_1.pdf)

What is "It was round the part of the day" in the quote below

> It was round the part of the day when I usually help Pa out in the
>   field with the crops.

Source: Gone Swift as Dust, The Reading & Writing Project

Comment: I'm pretty sure _round_ here is an informal shortening or _around_.

Answer (score 5):

The *a* in *around* is often clipped in informal or conversational speech, and the writer was imitating speech.

The clearest way to write that would have been to use an apostrophe to acknowledge the omission:

> It was 'round the part of the day when I usually help Pa out in the field with the crops.

Comment: Thanks. That's for the omission but what about the rest I mean "**the part of**" in "around the part the day"? Around noon?

Comment: *Around* in this sense means *near.*

Comment: Thanks once again. I understand the meaning of around. It's just "the part of day" I don't get it? In other words, could you give a time in the hours as in 11:00 AM, or 02:00 PM, etc.?

Comment: @learner The whole phrase is "the part of the day when I usually help Pa out in the field with the crops."  So, it's whenever the speaker usually helps their father with the crops.  It may be around 2 PM, in which case the phrase is like saying "It was around 2 PM."  I would imagine it's in the afternoon, but it seems the author is being intentionally vague and inexact.

Comment: +1 @cbh Ah, I get it. Thanks a lot.  Now I see I need to take a break. It is round the part of the day when I get really beat!

Answer (score 0):

Here ***[round](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/around)*** means approximately, about:

For usage of around vs round:

***[Around and round](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/around-or-round)*** are prepositions or adverbs. We use around and round when we refer to movements in circles or from one place to another. Around and round can both be used. Around is more common in American English. Round is a little more common in speaking:

> - The earth goes round the sun. (movement in circles)
> - We spent a very pleasant day walking round the town. (movement from one place to another)
> - Now they are retired, they are planning a trip around the world.

Cambridge Dictionary